# How to make an "adult content warning" on a static website?

Tags: javascript, html, jekyll, hugo

How can a static website (for example one built using Hugo or Jekyll) implement an "adult content warning"?

Ideally it should remember the user so they don't have to answer the question every time.

I'm asking for a friend.

Comment: *"I'm asking for a friend."* ***LOL***

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't really a website to ask for suggestions or ideas.

Answer (score 3):

The standard way to do this is to use `localStorage` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Local_storage) | [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/)) to save a flag indicating that the user has already seen and agreed to the warning. (A decade ago it might have been a cookie, but web storage has near universal support now.)

But note that if the site is for adult material, many visitors will be in private browsing mode, and their `localStorage` for the site will be deleted when the private browsing tab is closed. So it will be of limited use (to those visitors).